# Problem with xtensor xt::where index related function

Tags: c++, indexing, conditional-statements, where-clause, xtensor

Here I'm trying to do a very basic operation with the [xtensor](https://xtensor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library in C++. I have the xarray `a`, and with the [index related function](https://xtensor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/index_related.html?highlight=where#_CPPv4I0EN2xt5whereEDaRK1T) `xt::where`, I want to get an array of indexes where the condition holds True (beware, there is another xt::where function, but it is an [operator function](https://xtensor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/operators.html?highlight=where#_CPPv4I000EN2xt5whereEDaRR2E1RR2E2RR2E3) and I don't want it).
When I try to compile it, with this line, I get a lot of errors:

```
g++ -I/usr/include/xtensor -I/usr/local/include/xtl getindx.cpp -o getindx
```

Curiously, when I try to use the other xt::where function (the operator function), it works and compiles and runs. I'm clearly missing something; I search for it, but I can't get through, please help me! Thank you.

Here is the code:

```
#include "xtensor/xarray.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xio.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xview.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xoperation.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xtensor.hpp"


using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv){

  xt::xarray<double> arr {5.0, 6.0, 7.0};
  auto idx = xt::where(arr >= 6);

  std::cout << idx << std::endl;

 return 0;

}
```

EDIT: the error.

```
error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘std::vector<std::vector<long unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::vector<long unsigned int> > >’)
   std::cout << idx << std::endl;
```

EDIT2: solved without xtensor. Maybe it will be a bit slower.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){

 
  std::vector<double> arr{5.0,6.0,7.0};
  std::vector<unsigned int> indices;
  
  auto ptr = &bits[0];
  for (int i = 0; i<arr.size(); i++, ptr++)
    {
      if (*ptr>=6) indices.push_back (i);    
   }

  for (int i=0; i<indices.size(); i++){
    cout << "indices= "indices[i] << endl;
  } //output: indices=1, indices=2.
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have an extra `)` in `auto idx = xt::where(arr >= 6));`.

Comment: So where are the errors?

Comment: yes, the ")" was a slip when I copied the code. I edit the post and add the error!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `xt::where` (or maybe the syntax `xt::argwhere` is more descriptive here) returns an `std::vector` or array indices for which there is no `operator<<` overload e.g. for printing.

To deal with this `xt::from_indices` was created. From [the relevant docs page](https://xtensor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/indices.html):

```cpp
int main()
{
    xt::xarray<size_t> a = xt::arange<size_t>(3 * 4);

    a.reshape({3,4});

    auto idx = xt::from_indices(xt::argwhere(a >= 6));

    std::cout << idx << std::endl;
}
```

In this case `idx` can also be typed `xt::xarray<size_t>` or `xt::xtensor<size_t, 2>` if you'd want to be more verbose that with `auto`.